# What is the minimum space for keeping a horse?

Tags: containment, horses

I was wondering what the minimum space is for keeping a horse. I would like a horse but don't have much room so I was wondering what the minimum space is for keeping a horse?

Comment: tough question- I'm in the city - I have two horses on 2 acres, I wouldn't put anymore horses on there and it's the minimum space I'll go to. I had them on less, and it was unpleasant. Plenty of people put them on smaller lots.

Comment: If you want to have one horse, not two or more, you should look for other horse owners or a stall where your horse can stay and have social contacts. And then mostly it is not a matter of space but money.

Answer (score 4):

More than physical space, owning a horse requires significant investment of time and money. How much space a horse needs shouldn't be the main question of whether or not to get a horse.

That being said, the answer is...it depends. Big active horses will 'require' more space than little old ponies. There is not really a minimum space needed to keep a horse, in that a horse can probably survive in very cramped conditions. It might not be happy, but it can survive.

Horses will require space to live, i.e. a barn or stall. The exact amount of space needed will vary by horse. I would say that for the average horse to be able to comfortably turn around you should not be any smaller than 10x10 feet of living space, but ideally larger.

For turnout, it's really a matter of opinion. I'd like a horse to have at least half an acre to roam around and graze. Otherwise the land will risk getting over-grazed. If you commit to daily rides and  extensive exercise of your horse off property, then you may be able to get away with housing a horse on less land.

Comment: Horses do not need to be stabled or stalled - they need shelter from the elements and do better when not stabled and can run around - provided they have shelter and are adequately rugged against the environment

Comment: @Yvette Yes, horses don't *need* a stall, but they do need "space to live" as stated in the answer. It is largely a matter of opinion of whether a stall is recommended. I was assuming the questioner was tight for space, in which case keeping a horse in a stall is the most space-efficient solution. There is also a safety factor for both owner and horse; a stalled horse can be more easily caught when needed, and may be less likely to be injured by other horses or objects in the pasture. But horses can survive in fairly minimalist enclosures if provided appropriate care.